# Android Studio not starting in Ubuntu 20.04, since I edited the vmoptions from within the Andrioid Studio Settings

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

Android Studio not starting in Ubuntu 20.04, since I edited the vmoptions from within the Android Studio Settings.

The terminal output after running `./studio.sh` :

```
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4096m # <------ increase this to most of your RAM
```

[image: A screenshot of the terminal output and the vmoptions in text editor:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to home and delete the .config file